# merging two files with similar columns

Tags: perl

I have a two tab separated files that I need to align together. for example:

```
File 1:      File 2:
AAA 123      BBB 345
BBB 345      CCC 333
CCC 333      DDD 444
```

(These are large files, potentially thousands of lines!)

What I would like to do is to have the output look like this:

```
AAA 123
BBB 345  BBB 345
CCC 333  CCC 333
         DDD 444
```

Preferably I would like to do this in perl, but not sure how. any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960275/how-can-match-records-in-two-files-using-perl

Comment: do you really need to repeat the row label every time? building a hash of arrayrefs would be quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

If its just about making a data structure, this can be quite easy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# usage: script.pl file1 file2 ...

use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, $value) = split;
  push @{$data{$key}}, $value;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%data;
```

You can then output in any format you like. If its really about using the files exactly as they are, then its a little bit more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are sorted,

```
sub get {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   my $line = <$fh>;
   return () if !defined($line);
   return split(' ', $line);
}

my ($key1, $val1) = get($fh1);
my ($key2, $val2) = get($fh2);

while (defined($key1) && defined($key2)) {
   if ($key1 lt $key2) {
       print(join("\t", $key1, $val1), "\n");
       ($key1, $val1) = get($fh1);
   }
   elsif ($key1 gt $key2) {
       print(join("\t", '', '', $key2, $val2), "\n");
       ($key2, $val2) = get($fh2);
   }
   else {
       print(join("\t", $key1, $val1, $key2, $val2), "\n");
       ($key1, $val1) = get($fh1);
       ($key2, $val2) = get($fh2);
   }
}

while (defined($key1)) {
   print(join("\t", $key1, $val1), "\n");
   ($key1, $val1) = get($fh1);
}

while (defined($key2)) {
   print(join("\t", '', '', $key1, $val1), "\n");
   ($key2, $val2) = get($fh2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As ikegami mentioned, it assumes that the files' contents are arranged as shown in your example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file1, '<file1.txt' or die $!;
open my $file2, '<file2.txt' or die $!;

my $file1_line = <$file1>;
print $file1_line;

while ( my $file2_line = <$file2> ) {
    if( defined( $file1_line = <$file1> ) ) {
        chomp $file1_line;
        print $file1_line;
    }

    my $tabs = $file1_line ? "\t" : "\t\t";
    print "$tabs$file2_line";
}

close $file1;
close $file2;
```

Reviewing your example, you show some identical key/value pairs in both files.  Given this, it looks like you want to show the pair(s) unique to file 1, unique to file 2, and show the common pairs.  If this is the case (and you're not trying to match the files' pairs by either keys or values), you can `use List::Compare:`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

open my $file1, '<file1.txt' or die $!;
my @file1 = <$file1>;
close $file1;

open my $file2, '<file2.txt' or die $!;
my @file2 = <$file2>;
close $file2;

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@file1, \@file2);

my @file1Only = $lc->get_Lonly; # L(eft array)only
for(@file1Only) { print }

my @bothFiles = $lc->get_intersection;
for(@bothFiles) { chomp; print "$_\t$_\n" }

my @file2Only = $lc->get_Ronly; # R(ight array)only
for(@file2Only) { print "\t\t$_" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Joel Berger's answer, but this approach allows to you keep track of whether files did or did not contain a given key:

```
my %data;

while (my $line = <>){
    chomp $line;
    my ($k)          = $line =~ /^(\S+)/;
    $data{$k}{line}  = $line;
    $data{$k}{$ARGV} = 1;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%data);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'CCC' => {
    'other.dat' => 1,
    'data.dat' => 1,
    'line' => 'CCC 333'
  },
  'BBB' => {
    'other.dat' => 1,
    'data.dat' => 1,
    'line' => 'BBB 345'
  },
  'DDD' => {
    'other.dat' => 1,
    'line' => 'DDD 444'
  },
  'AAA' => {
    'data.dat' => 1,
    'line' => 'AAA 123'
  }
};
```